# School managment application classes can't work in navigation menu

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have displayed all the classes stored in my database and I want to display those classes in my navigation menu so that user can click on particular class but it doesn't work. Following is my code.

[image: navigation page image is showed here]

Comment: paste the code, not the image.

Comment: Don't you think you have to end if which you started in "Li" class attribute i.e. endif

Comment: no needed @WajahatHashmi as he want only one line statement to execute

Comment: i have closed if function which i have started in <li> class attribute but now it's not showing me anything

Comment: Try giving the brace in line `<?php if($row['c_id'] == $c_id) { echo 'active'; } ?>` and check again.

Comment: and keep code simple. :) 
make href as `echo base_url('admin/subjects/'.$row['c_name'])`. 

wait a minute. `Is c_name in all Caps, as same in database?`

Comment: yes, c_name is same throughout my application i have accessed it in my functions like in sections, subjects, teacher etc